# End To End Encrypted Chat Application using Windows Forms and . Net C#. Where do I start with encryption?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, signalr, diffie-hellman

I have an assignment at school to create a chat application. I have created this using SignalR to ensure real time communication. However, our teacher wanted also end to end encryption.

I have 2 projects: 1 server (which contains the hub) and the Client, which communicates directly with the database to load the messages on log-in. When a user is online, the user communicates directly through SignalR connections.

**I need to find a way to make this communication secure (teacher suggested Diffie Hellman to exchange keys). It would really be appreciated if any of you guys could put me on the right road where to start or if you could suggest me some articles which could help.**

*Note: I am a Java Developer and am new to .Net Framework and C#.*

*If any of you is interested here is the github link to my project: https://github.com/joanjanku2000/chat-app/tree/jjanku/feature/chat-app*

Comment: The problem with any kind of key exchange is that a MITM can intercept the exchange attempts and basically perform two key exchanges, one with Alice and one with Bob, both then thinking they are secure while actually they only encrypt to the MITM which then re-encrypts to the other party. 
If that scenario is of no concern you can do those key exchanges and you as the server can then claim to not know what is in the messages.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think man in the middle should not be allowed to see the messages that's why Diffie Hellman was suggested

Comment: All kinds of key exchange can be intercepted unless you use a different and already trusted channel, the most secure one being sitting next to each other and manually sharing the keys.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read documentation first in order to choose the right encoding/decoding technique.

Read these :

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cryptography-model
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/generating-keys-for-encryption-and-decryption
- **https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/encryption-and-decryption-using-a-symmetric-key-in-c-sharp/**

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the articles. Is there any article in high level, telling how to perform the encryption, not the actual code. I mean like for ex: Where to store the keys in a chat app ? How to encrypt the database messages ? Should i use 2 different approaches or one ?

Comment: How to reach end-to-end encryption so the server can't see the messages ? If i send the messages in the server, encrypt thm there and store them in the database, it is not end to end encryption

Comment: "End-To-End encryption" means that the message is encrypted from the client just before sending it, then travels securely thru the network to the database server where it stays encrypted, then is sent to the targeted clients who are the only one than can read it. It's like Whataspp messages. So you will have to encrypt locally before sending it. And both sender and reader must share the encryption/decryption key to send/read the message. Try to adapt the code example in the articles to you needs.

Comment: KISS (keep it simple and stupid). Just store the encryption/decryption key in the app.config file of the client app. No need to use sophisticated techniques here.

Comment: https://www.cometchat.com/blog/whatsapps-architecture-and-system-design